# How do I shift a door's latch hole and strike plate up or down half an inch?

Tags: doors

I have a few interior doors that do not latch closed because the bolting mechanism and latch hole are vertically misaligned. If I remove the strike plate I can extend the size of the latch hole, but then one of the screw holes of the strike plate ends up over the (now bigger) latch hole and the screw won't hold.

(Note: I don't want to move the door hinges since the doors align nicely in the casings.)

Comment: how much is the misalignment? also a longer screw will go in the stud and hold even if the old latch hole is there

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can, glue a plug into the latch hole and similarly drill out the existing screw holes with a 1/4" bit and glue plugs of 1/4" dowel into them.

Now you have a blank slate to re-locate the strike plate wherever you want to.  Use a spade bit for the latch hole (3/4" or 7/8" or 1" - use the whatever is closest to the size of the strikeplate hole).

Comment: Thanks, this worked out pretty well. I should mention that the strike plate is recessed into the casing so that the plate and casing surfaces are flush. This means that there is now a half inch of indentation above the strike plate from its old location. However, after a bit of paint it is barely noticeable.

Comment: What exactly is a plug?

Answer (score 2):

You can put in a "dutchman" into the existing hole in the jamb and then rebore the hole / mortise the strike.

A dutchman is nothing more than a wood "patch".  If you have a Fein Multimaster type tool (oscillating saw), it's pretty easy to do - especially if it's paint grade trim.

Answer (score 2):

The answers above are the correct and proper ways.

However, an alternative way is to  temporarily screw a piece of 3/4" wood over the new hole location and drill from there.  The plywood will keep your hole saw straight.  Then you can purchase an oversized plate made for the thickness of your door that wraps around the strike.  Doesn't look good, makes it look like you repaired door when after it got kicked in.